# Blazor Change Validation default CSS class names

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-validation

I'm trying Microsoft Blazor and when working with forms and validation I stopped on how can I change the default CSS class that will be added by default on `InputText` Validation State.

For Explanation when `InputText` has an error by default take class "`invalid`" I want to change this class to "`is-invalid`"

I need best practices.

Thanks, StackOverflow community

Comment: Good question - Microsoft is too Bootstrap centric :)

Answer (score 4):

This is now customizable, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#custom-validation-class-attributes

```
var editContext = new EditContext(model);
editContext.SetFieldCssClassProvider(new MyFieldClassProvider());

...

private class MyFieldClassProvider : FieldCssClassProvider
{
    public override string GetFieldCssClass(EditContext editContext, 
        in FieldIdentifier fieldIdentifier)
    {
        var isValid = !editContext.GetValidationMessages(fieldIdentifier).Any();

        return isValid ? "good field" : "bad field";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This solved my issue also.

Answer (score 2):

Yes true it's customizable in Core 5.0, but the examples given is not working as is. The method `HandleSubmit` must take `EditContext` as argument, and the custom `FieldCssClassProvider` be set there, not in `OnInitialized()` as in the examples.

```c
    private async Task HandleSubmit(EditContext context)
    {
        context.SetFieldCssClassProvider(new MyFieldClassProvider());
        var isValid = context.Validate();

        if (isValid)
        {
            //...
        }
        else
        {
            //...
        }
```

My `MyFieldClassProvider()` returns "`is-valid`" and "`is-invalid`" and this works with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Any HTML element (or InputText) attribute including the class, can be 'one-way' bound to a variable or expression. So in your case, you could do:

```
<input type="text" class="@((any_validation_condition)? "error_css_class" : "")" />
```

or just bind to a variable and set that variable at run-time to reflect the suitable display class of the element.

Thanks

Comment: thanks @Samer_Awajan you are right but i think this not the best solution i need to change the default css class itself 
ex. current rendered as <input type="text" class="form-control invalid">
but i need this <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid">

Comment: @EngrRslan But I think that is what is just explained here

Comment: I got what you mean. It seems the css class for invalid input is glued in the validation logic as a sort of convention. I research the SDK of the components and could not find a way to modify this convention 'invalid'. So, I think you have two options, either modify the css of 'invalid' to 'is-invalid' so you get the expected look, or do custom vlidation of the model on your own and control the css class as mentioned above. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Blazor has arbitrarily picked `invalid` as the css class for `InputBase<T>` based items' validation, like `InputText`. You can however create a new control like `MyInputText.razor` inherit from these and make your own control and put intermediary code in place.

In this case you can string replace (but prepend with space character!) the `CssClass` property replacing  `invalid` for  `is-invalid`, and/or  `valid` for  `is-valid`. You could make a helper method or simply do it inline:

```
@inherits Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputText
<input @attributes="@AdditionalAttributes" class="@CssClass.Replace(" valid", " is-valid").Replace(" invalid", " is-invalid")" @bind="@CurrentValueAsString" />
```

and use it as you would a normal `InputText`:

```
<MyInputText @bind-Value="yourModel.Foo" class="form-control" />
```

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to @user774031 answer:
Blazor Framework Adds an Id to Isolated css class to make them scoped to Razor component but since this Id attribute added on Runtime, they do not add to child InputComponent and so the css class defined using css isolation do not apply and we should define them globally. To make them work as isolated css class define them as below for example:
1- Define a .Net class which inherit from `FieldCssClassProvider` and override its `GetFieldCssClass` method. This method should
return some `string` as classname from `editcontext` and `fieldIdentifier` object.

```
public class MyCustomeCSSProvider : FieldCssClassProvider
    {
        public override string GetFieldCssClass(EditContext editContext, in FieldIdentifier fieldIdentifier)
        {
            string className = string.Empty;
            if (editContext.IsModified(fieldIdentifier))
            {
                className += " modifiedField";
            }
            if (editContext.GetValidationMessages(fieldIdentifier).Any())
            {
                className += " invalidField";
            }
            else
            {
                className += " validField";
            }
            return className;
        }

    }
```

2- in `OnInitialized` life cycle Set CssClassProvider for edit context using extension method:

```
_context = new EditContext(student);
_context.SetFieldCssClassProvider(new MyCustomeCSSProvider());
```

3- Define your class in isolated css files as below using `::deep` :

```
::deep .validField {
    border-color: lawngreen;
}

::deep .invalidField {
    background-color: tomato;
}
::deep .modifiedField {
    border: yellow dashed 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late the party on this one but to style the validation messages themselves I did this:

```
<div class="text-danger mt-2">
    <ValidationMessage For="()=>_model.Field" ></ValidationMessage>
</div>
```