# How can I change css directly(without variable) in Blazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I am using the server-side of Blazor.

I want to change the CSS of the body.

In Jquery I can write the code like this easily:

```
$("body").css("overflow-y","hidden");
```

However, with this tutorial([Blazor Change Validation default css class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58199723/blazor-change-validation-default-css-class-names)) said, it seems I can only change the CSS by changing the class name.

It is so complex while crossing the component, especially the body is at the top of all the components.

I wonder whether there is a way can changes CSS directly in Blazor. Thank you.

Comment: You can do this without changing the class name, but can you really justify the effort when CSS classes work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, Blazor does not support direct css modification yet, since Web Assembly doesn't. Anyway heads up, it is on the road-map for Web Assembly/Blazor.

Therefor your best bet is, changing the class name with variables. At least for now.

Answer (score 31):

There are several ways of getting out of the "blazor way" of doing things and accomplishing css modification of an element.

**Simplest**: Just like you can use the class attribute, use the style attribute

```
<element style=@myStyle></element>

@code {
  string myStyle;

  void MyMethod() {
     myStyle="overflow-y: hidden;"
  }
}
```

**Advanced**: Use JS interop

a. In the main view (`index.html` or `Pages/_Host.cshtml` depending on project type), create a js endpoint for your component

```
<script>
   window.applyStyleForElement = function(styleOp) {
       document.getElementById(styleOp.id).style[styleOp.attrib] = styleOp.value;
   }
</script>
```

b. In razor file:

```
@Inject IJRRuntime JSRuntime
<element id=@myId></element>

@code {
  string myId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");

  async Task MyMethod() {
     await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync("applyStyleForElement", 
      new { id = myId,  attrib = "overflowY", value = "hidden" });
  }
}
```

Finally, applying to your special case with body element ("advanced" method above).

a. In the main view (`index.html` or `Pages/_Host.cshtml` depending on project type), create a js endpoint

```
<script>
   window.applyStyleForBody = function(style) {
       document.body.style[style.attrib] = style.value;
   }
</script>
```

b. In razor file:

```
@Inject IJRRuntime JSRuntime
(...)

@code {

  async Task MyMethod() {
     await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync("applyStyleForBody", 
       new { attrib = "overflowY", value = "hidden" });
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think setting the style attribute is hacky, in fact it's pretty much the standard way of setting Blazor attributes.

Comment: Nice details. Related video segment from Oct 2021 discussing bindings among other things [ASP.NET Community Standup - Blazor Native Interop with SkiaSharp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVWQkpcVEWQ&list=PLdo4fOcmZ0oX-DBuRG4u58ZTAJgBAeQ-t&t=758s)

Answer (score 3):

I'M NOT SURE IT'S THE RECOMMENDED WAY BUT it works!

For one of my project, I include a  in the page html itself, using params :

```
<style>

    html 
    {
        background-color:@_ColorCss;
    }

</style>
```

```
//html stuff here
```

```
@code
{
    public string Color{ get; set; } = "white";
    string _ColorCss => $"{Color}";     //use this in case of formatting (ex : add 'px' or that kind of things)

    //code stuff here  
}
```

not the very sexiest way but it works

have fun !

Comment: If anybody has a way to add the CSS in side appart file, but with the possibility to use kind of params, up me :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually there is a way to do that and it works really good (it might suffer a little delay though).
I know this answer is a little bit late but it might help other people who face the same challenge.

1. We need to create some JS code that includes the wanted files:

   ```
   function includeLeftStyle() {
       appendStyle("left.css");
   }

   function includeRightStyle() {
       appendStyle("right.css");
   }

   function appendStyle(path) {
       var element = document.createElement("link");
       element.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
       element.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
      element.setAttribute("href", path);
      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(element);
   }
   ```
2. The wished CSS can be called according to the language (any other coditions) in the MainLayout:

   ```
   protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
   {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            if (// is left)
            {
                await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("includeLeftStyle");
            }
            else
            {
                await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("includeRightStyle");
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Beginnig from the @Tewr answer, we can also change the whole class:

a) In the main view (index.html or Pages/_Host.cshtml depending on project type), create a js endpoint

```
<script> 
    window.applyStyleForElement = function (styleOp) { 
        if (styleOp != null) { 
            document.getElementById(styleOp.id).className = styleOp.value; 
        } 
} 
</script>
```

b) Then in the razor file

```
async Task MyMethod(string sortColumn) 
{
    await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("applyStyleForElement", 
         new { id = sortColumn, value = "newClassName" });
}
```