# How to dynamically change HTML background using C# in Blazor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, blazor, webassembly

Javascript can easily manipulate DOM elements as well as css to dynamically change the appearance of the application. I would like to dynamically change the background image of the DOM element dynamically using c# in a blazor application.

```js
document.getElementById('the_body').style.backgroundImage = "something.gif"


$('body').css('backgroundImage', 'url(something.gif)');
```

```css
body
{
    background: #000000 url(images/back_all.gif) repeat-x top;
    font: 12px Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #666666;
}
```

How do I obtain the same result in C# Blazor application?

Comment: Would it not be the same as any other scripting, where the @code block modifies string variable @v (containing either the url to one image, or the name of one css class) so i contains a different URL/css class, and the markup dictates the element style's background/css class shall use @v? For example [one way might be](https://blazor-tutorial.net/one-way-data-binding) (it feels like the question is very simple, so much so that I wonder if I've misunderstood something??)

Comment: check this answer, seems you should rather set the class name https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280795/how-can-i-change-css-directlywithout-variable-in-blazor , or need to set the style as string

Comment: Caius Jard it may be a simple question but from the reply made by Bassie, when I follow the link it seems Blazor does not have a way to interact directly with CSS at the moment. I wanted to directly interact with the css document like the way JScript does. I know I can use @code block to do somethings if I write an inline style in my HTML document. excuse my grammar. English is not my first language

Comment: Have a look at this source. https://github.com/BrianLParker/CleanView

Answer (score 0):

To change the background (or anything for that matter) of an element that you have in a component, you can declare private fields, or use some similar pattern:

```
<div style="background-image: url(@backgroundUrl)">
</div>
<button type="button" @onclick="ChangeBackground">Change above div's background</button>

@code {
    string backgroundUrl = "default.jpg";

    private void ChangeBackground()
    {
        backgroundUrl = "some-other-image.jpg";
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```